# Submit only when ENTER is pressed. 

Tags: php, jquery

I am having difficulties making this script to work bacause I am not a jQuery expert.
Here's what I have got so far.

It doesn't alert when <kbd>ENTER</kbd> was pressed.

I want this to happen in a very Facebook manner.

I have a textarea with `id="textboxcontent<?= $id?>"`.

I don't know if I am heading on the right track but least I tried =P

```
var Id = element.attr("id");
$('input#textboxcontent'+Id).keypress(function(e) {



        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
        var element = $(this);
        var Id = element.attr("id");
        var test = $("#textboxcontent"+Id).val();
        var dataString = 'comment='+ test + '&pid=' + Id;
        //var text = $(this).val();


        var commentContainer = $(this).parents('tr');

        if(test=='' || test == 'Write a Comment'){
            //==alert("Your comment can't be blank");
            //$("#textboxcontent"+Id).focus();
        } else {
            $("#flash"+Id).show();
            $("#flash"+Id).fadeIn(400).html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" align="absmiddle"><font size="-2">chotto matte</font>');


            commentContainer.animate({ opacity : 0.5}, 500);
            commentContainer.find("#comment-loader").fadeIn(500);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost/rara/index.php/xtr/add_comment",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html){
                        $("#loadplace"+Id).append(html);
                        //document.getElementById('textboxcontent' + +Id).value='';
                        $("#textboxcontent"+Id).attr( { value : " "  });
                        $('#textboxcontent').value='';
                        $("#flash"+Id).hide();

                        commentContainer.css({opacity : 1});

                        commentContainer.find("#comment-loader").fadeOut(100);
                        commentContainer.find('.panel').hide();
                        $(".comment-textarea").css({height : "30px" });
                        $('.delete-button').hide();



                    }
                });

        }

        } else {
            //alert
        }
          return false;
    });
```

Comment: You need to simplify your question. The keypress event works fine, there must be something in the later code or how you are reading the id from element the first time that causes it to not work. http://jsfiddle.net/2Eszk/

Comment: <?= ?> is a shorthand for <? echo  ?>

Comment: @xxxo_tryme: it alerts `enter`. (Chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#textboxcontent').keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
           //your other codes here
```